# Replicação de Frame [Erro: Component already exists]

Tags: delphi, orientação-a-objetos, delphi-7, pascal, object-pascal

Tenho um form no delphi e queria que ao clicar em um botão um frame pré criado fosse adicionado dinamicamente várias vezes. Estou tentando através desse código:

```
procedure TMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i:integer; frame:TFrame;
begin

  for i:=0 to 5 do
    begin
      frame := Tframe.create(self);
      with frame do
        begin
        parent:= self;
        left:= 376 + (i*220);
        top:= 136 + (i*332);
        end;
    end;

end;
```

Ao executar sou notificado do seguinte erro:

> "A component named Frame already exists"

Já procurei em vários sites e não acho a solução desse problema.
Achei uma questão quase idêntica nesse [link](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/29/309397.html) mas sem solução.

Comment: Seu código funciona perfeitamente aqui. tem algo a mais no seu código ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma solução simples é colocar um nome para cada frame criado. Fica assim:

```
procedure TMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
    i:integer; 
    frame:TFrame;
begin    
    for i := 0 to 5 do
    begin
        frame := Tframe.create(self);
        frame.name := 'MeuFrame' + IntToStr(i);
        with frame do
        begin
            parent:= self;
            left:= 376 + (i*220);
            top:= 136 + (i*332);
        end;
    end;    
end;
```

Comment: +1 bastaria o cara ter lido a mensagem de erro de retorno: JÁ EXISTE.